# Create conditional factor based on counts within a separate level

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have what I think should be a relatively simple problem. I have a large data set of thousands of observations taken from different areas within distinct sites, the general structure is something like:

```
df <- data.frame(Site = as.factor(rep(c("Site.A","Site.B","Site.C"), 5)),
                   Response = as.numeric(runif(15, 0, 10)),
                   Habitat = as.factor(c("G","G","F","G","F",
                                         "F","F","F","G","S",
                                         "S", "S", "S","S","S")))
```

I would like to add a column identifying the dominant habitat in each site based on the counts of the habitats in each site (i.e. whatever habitat makes of the majority of observations within each site).

This should be relatively easy with something along the lines of:

```
dat %>%
  group_by(Site) %>%
  mutate(Dominant_Habitat = if_else(
    (count(Habitat == "G") >=3, "G",
    (count(Habitat == "F") >= 3, "F", "S"))
```

but for the life of me can’t find a way to make it work.
Thanks,

Comment: How about ties? In your example data, `Site.A` has 2 `G` and 2 `S`. Which one or both do you want to keep?

Comment: Good point - I simplified the example a bit to get a general approach. For the example though lets say we would reclassify as a new mixed-habitat factor (e.g., "G/S" for Site A).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `count` and `slice` the the most frequent `Habitat`(maybe with ties) in each `Site`, and then join back to the initial dataset.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  count(Site, Habitat) %>%
  group_by(Site) %>%
  slice_max(n) %>%
  summarise(Dominant_Habitat = paste(Habitat, collapse = '/')) %>%
  left_join(df, ., by = "Site")

     Site  Response Habitat Dominant_Habitat
1  Site.A 2.6751221       G              G/S
2  Site.B 7.0941244       G              F/S
3  Site.C 3.3727804       F              F/S
4  Site.A 2.4453809       G              G/S
5  Site.B 2.0155192       F              F/S
6  Site.C 6.8103549       F              F/S
7  Site.A 9.5722247       F              G/S
8  Site.B 8.7405261       F              F/S
9  Site.C 1.0035530       G              F/S
10 Site.A 4.5928348       S              G/S
11 Site.B 5.6210020       S              F/S
12 Site.C 8.2221709       S              F/S
13 Site.A 0.3368293       S              G/S
14 Site.B 0.4153831       S              F/S
15 Site.C 6.0440495       S              F/S
```